# Programmatic, "non-dynamic" construction of HQL queries within the bounds of the JPA

Tags: java, jpa, hql, dsl

Example:

```
List<Object[]> list = em.createQuery(
  "SELECT 'Foo', 123 FROM IrcEvent ev", Object[].class).getResultList();
```

What I don't like in that example:

- How do I know the table name? Can't I specify the entity class instead?
- How do I know the column name? [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org) provides auto-completion by creating a DSL from the database schema.
- There could be syntax errors everywhere.

What I basically want is something like

```
entityManager.deleteAll(EntityClass.class);
```

to delete the rows of an antire table (for example).

Comment: HQL doesn't use table names, but entity class names. You can use "select e.foo, e.bar from " + MyEntity.class + " e". But it's less readable, and you should have unit tests for your query anyway, which would detect a name problem. named queries are also checked at deploy time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA 2 Criteria API http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjitv.html is for creating type safe queries programmatically, but it does not support deletes

Comment: Is there any method to determine table names in a type-safe way?

Comment: @user1050755 Is there a specific reason why you are not using hibernate with spring? As far as I know your table names will be bound to real objects and if you want to truncate a table all you need to do is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262723/using-hibernate-hql-to-truncate-a-table